# How to include a third-party library in local build for Particle (Spark)?

Tags: c++, embedded

I have code for a Particle Photon that I can compile using the [web IDE](https://build.particle.io). I am using the [MPU6050 library for Particle](https://github.com/pkourany/I2CDEV_MPU6050), so the IDE added the line:

```c
#include <MPU6050.h>
```

I want to compile it locally and follow [these instructions](https://docs.particle.io/support/particle-tools-faq/local-build/). I get the error

```
app.cpp:2:21: fatal error: MPU6050.h: No such file or directory
```

I cloned the Github repository and added its path to the environment variable `LIBRARY_PATH` but I still get the same error.

[This thread](https://community.particle.io/t/how-to-include-library-files-using-particle-build-ide/26141) mentions a similar problem with the Particle dev but does not detail the solution.

How can I compile locally with a third-party library?

Answer (score 1):

If you read further, [the instructions page](https://docs.particle.io/support/particle-tools-faq/local-build/) has a section on third-party libraries:

> To use libraries with local build you should use the extended project structure within the APPDIR.
>   It looks like this:
>
> - myappdir
>
>   - project.properties
>   - src
>
>     - myapp.cpp
>   - lib
>
> If you have a project in the extended format, building with APPDIR
>   automatically builds all of the libraries in lib as well, and all of the src
>   directories in the libraries are added to the include search path, so for
>   example you can just: `#include "neopixel.h"`

You could also use the same extended project structure and `git clone` the Github repository into `lib`.

Note that the local build is less forgiving than the web IDE, for example you will not be able to use functions before declaring them.

Comment: the file name suffix: `cpp` indicates the code is written in C++,  so please change the tag from `c` to `c++`.   Those are two different languages (and becoming more different with each new release of the language manual